# Give permission to another user to google sheet using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, permissions

I currently have code to upload data to a google sheet in google drive. However, I want to give another user access to this google sheet. I tried some code that I found online to give access to another user, included below, but that code gave me an error, also included below.

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
#drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Please set worksheet names.
sheetNameForWorksheet1 = "Report Overview"
sheetNameForWorksheet2 = "Error Details"
sheetNameForWorksheet3 = "% of missing values per column"

# Please set values for each worksheet. Values are 2 dimensional array.
valuesForWorksheet1 = overview_df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
valuesForWorksheet2 = details_df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
valuesForWorksheet3 = miss_occ_df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()

spreadsheet = {
    'properties': {
        'title': 'Data Integrity Report Completed on {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    },
    "sheets": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "title": sheetNameForWorksheet1
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "title": sheetNameForWorksheet2
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "title": sheetNameForWorksheet3
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
gsheet_id = spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')

batch_update_values_request_body = {
    "data": [
        {
            "values": valuesForWorksheet1,
            "range": sheetNameForWorksheet1,
        },
        {
            "values": valuesForWorksheet2,
            "range": sheetNameForWorksheet2,
        },
        {
            "values": valuesForWorksheet3,
            "range": sheetNameForWorksheet3,
        }
    ],
    "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"
}

response = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=gsheet_id, body=batch_update_values_request_body).execute()
```

I found this code online and tried it:

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3')
domain_permission = {
                'type': 'domain',
                'role': 'writer',
                'emailAddress': 'example@gmail.com',
                # Magic almost undocumented variable which makes files appear in your Google Drive
                'allowFileDiscovery': True,
            }

req = drive.permissions().create(fileId=gsheet_id, body=domain_permission, fields="id")
req.execute()
```

However, this gave me the following error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to create a permission for the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve them using google-api-python-client with Python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue:

> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

The reason of above error message is `drive = build('drive', 'v3')`. In this case, the access token for using the API is not included. So please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3')
```

To:

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

#### Note:

- In your situation, when the modified script is run, if the error of `Request had insufficient authentication scopes.` occurs, please do the following flow.

  1. Please add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to `SCOPE` like `SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]`.
  2. Please delete the file of `token.pickle` and authorize the scopes by running the script.

     - By this, the additional scope is reflected to the access token.
- This modified script supposes the settings of object of `domain_permission` are correct.

  - If you want to permit to edit as an user, please try the following object.

    ```
    domain_permission = {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'writer',
        'emailAddress': 'example@gmail.com'
    }
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. If other error occurs, can you show the error message? And also can you provide your whole script? By this, I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!

Comment: @user11371534 Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved.